# Set of convergence of sequence of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $G$ be a connected open set of the complex plane, let $F \subset G$ be a relatively closed set and $D$ be a proper dense set in $F$. Let $g_n : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of analytic functions. Assume $g_n$ converges uniformly in $G \smallsetminus F$ and that converges pointwisely in $D$. Can we deduce that $g_n$ converges uniformly in $G$? Can we estate a counterexample?

Thank you!

Comment: We cannot, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117633/a-question-about-the-limit-of-a-sequence-of-pointwise-convergent-analytic-funtio). However, a slightly different situation has an affirmative answer, called [mergelyan theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergelyan%27s_theorem#:~:text=From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free%20encyclopedia,every%20continuous%20function%20f%20%3A%20K)

Comment: there are relatively easy examples of functions $H_n$, that converge locally uniformly except at zero, where they converge pointwise (considering an entire function $h$ that is not constant but is bounded on any line through zero and taking $H(z)=(h(z)-h(0))/z^k, k \ge 1$ the order of $h(z)-h(0)$ at zero) and then $H_n(z)=H(nz)$); so one can take $G$ the unit disc, $F$ a small closed disc around the origin, $D$ anything you want that is dense in $F$ as then $H_n$ converges uniformly on any closed annulus that includes $G-F$, hence on $G-F$ and pointwise on $F$ hence on $D$